# Is there automated way to recognize and remove gitlab repo branches?

Tags: git, gitlab

I want to remove branches from projects that are more than year old. There are just too many to go through manually. I was wondering if there is an automated way to do this.

Comment: You'll need to figure out what conditions need to be met for you to know it's OK to delete a branch. Perhaps you could start here for sorting all branches, oldest first: `git branch -r --sort=committerdate`

Comment: Would list branches of all remote repositories?

Comment: That assumes you have each repo cloned, and it would list all remote *branches* per repo you run that command in. If you have many repos you'd either need to clone them all, or use an API if you don't want to clone them all. (Or maybe you could run a script on the server(s).)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the API. You can [list your projects](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/projects.html#list-all-projects) (or [list a groups projects](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/groups.html#list-a-groups-projects)) and use the results from that call to invoke the [list branches API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/branches.html#list-repository-branches) with each project ID to list all the branches for each project and retrieve the `commit.committed_date` field to get the date of the commit at the HEAD of that branch then use the [delete branch API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/branches.html#delete-repository-branch) to delete branches older than a particular date.

In Python using the [python-gitlab](https://python-gitlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) API wrapper:

```py
import gitlab
import datetime
from dateutil.parser import parse
gl = gitlab.Gitlab('https://gitlab.example.com', private_token='Your API token')

now = datetime.datetime.now().astimezone(datetime.timezone.utc)
THRESHOLD = now - datetime.timedelta(days=365)

for project in gl.projects.list(all=True):
    for branch in project.branches.list(all=True):
        commit = branch.commit
        date = parse(commit['committed_date'])
        if date < THRESHOLD:
            branch.delete()
```